# How can I verify if Read Committed Snapshot Isolation is causing application problems that Read Committed would not?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, monitoring, isolation-level

Suppose that I've turned on RCSI and my server is doing just fine; There have been no spikes in resource usage and the increased load on tempdb has been minimal. This is all good, but how can I tell if the change has caused my users problems? For example, for the purpose of finding issues caused by RSCI that Read Committed would have not caused are there any:

- Error messages that I can track?
- Diagnostic scripts I can run?
- Metrics to watch?
- Logging the application developers can put in their own code?
- Specific user complaints I should be on alert for?

I'm quite happy to use RCSI, but the purpose of this question is to find actionable ways to track the impact of turning it on after the fact.

Comment: I mean, what kind of issues are you trying to be proactive about?...really the main one would be logical issues with the data if you had use cases that are dependent on locking to function properly.

Comment: @J.D. I'm trying to watch for _anything at all_ that RCSI can make fail that wouldn't have failed under Read Committed. You're right that what you have suggested is probably the main issue, but how can I track that?

Comment: Have test cases built out, run them, check the results.

Comment: @SeanGallardy What kind of test cases? Do I need to set up some high concurrency stuff?

Comment: Whatever your client application or code currently does. Emulate the normal things your users do and overlap that with other stuff they do at the same time. You have expected results of it running like that in RC, you can compare the output to RCSI. If they are the same, no issues. If they are different...

Comment: "*Do I need to set up some high concurrency stuff?*" - Nope. Just any form of concurrency (if it's normal for your database to experience concurrency). Like Sean said, you'd just have to test the normal use cases both ways. But if you know your application and are sure that it doesn't require locking to logically function properly, then there's not much to be concerned with.

Comment: Primary issue in RCSI is write skew and tempdb usage.

Comment: @SeanGallardy, I think what the OP is saying tacitly, is that he doesn't know exactly what his current application does or what his users do. What he wants to know is (a) what *might* any application do which could be affected by a switch to RCSI, and (b) having enumerated the possibilities (of only the things which are relevant to the proposed change to RCSI), how *would* he detect in a systematic way whether his application is currently doing those things (and if so, is either suffering corruption now, or might suffer corruption under certain future conditions).

Comment: @Steve If that's the case, that's not a great question because it's too open ended. Asking those types of questions, "What are all the issues that could occur with my app I know nothing about if I do _insert item here_". If this were the case, I'd vote to close.

Comment: @SeanGallardy, I suspect the OP has not anticipated how difficult an answer would be, to a question that is essentially "what are the issues that could occur if I change one well-defined item of database configuration". I think it's a reasonable question. But I don't think advising him to set up a battery of test cases, as broadly as "all the things your users currently do", is a reasonable solution to suggest. Such an approach would be enormous if done by brute force without a prior narrowing analysis, and some faults would only manifest under highly specific schedules of execution.

Comment: @Steve I think it's an absolutely appropriate suggestion to a configuration change where the OP has no idea what will or will not be impacted. Quoting your own words, "Such an approach would be enormous if done by brute force without a prior narrowing analysis, and some faults would only manifest under highly specific schedules of execution." that's exactly what the OP is asking the answerer to do. You're advocating it's ok for the OP to do it, just not the answerer to point out this is too large of a scenario. Odd.

Comment: @SeanGallardy, point is, he's asking the question in earnest, and people who don't know things do potentially ask questions that involve too much to answer comprehensively. You didn't point out that the scenario was too large, which would be fine. You responded with a suggestion that could sound generally plausible, but any database expert would know is blatantly unworkable in the context of this particular question. With your additional remarks now, it seems like it must have been facetious.

Comment: @Steve It's entirely plausible and the remarks weren't facetious. The point is the question asked is extremely broad and requires knowledge of the use of the database to which we know nothing. Answering to a tip of the iceberg style question is either going to get you the same style response or generic answers that mean nothing to your specific environment. Making test cases and testing them is hardly so extensive it cannot be done. If the database is that complex, what makes you believe a generic answer here will be applicable to the environment?

Comment: @SeanGallardy, you don't need to know his specific database application, to answer the abstract question of what adverse effects RCSI could have on an application written to assume RCI. He can't be the first person in the world who has wanted to move from one to the other in order to gain the known advantages of RCSI over RCI (like non-blocking reads), so it's reasonable to think there might be material or expertise out there which covers this issue. (1/2)

Comment: As for test cases, you should be sufficiently experienced to know that proposing to brute-force test every algorithm in a reasonable-sized database application (for which many DBAs would not have the source code and design understanding), in every possible combination with each other and with every possible schedule of execution, in order to find every possible difference caused by isolation issues, not just in stored results but in the performance profile of execution, is practically impossible. No sensible practitioner would attempt the impossible. (2/2)

Comment: "you don't need to know his specific database application, to answer the abstract question of what adverse effects RCSI could have on an application written to assume RCI." This is horribly wrong. There's really no point in continuing the conversation as you've demonstrated that you're very unfamiliar with the topic based on the incorrect statements you've been making. Have a wonderful day, maybe use some of it to learn some more SQL Server stuff :) @Steve

Comment: @SeanGallardy, I think it's only "wrong" in your view because you don't know enough to actually make a reasonably comprehensive answer that enumerates the implications the change *could* have. Neither do I, but that doesn't make the question unreasonable to ask, unless questions are only reasonable when you know the answer to them. But I do know that you're completely wrong about the testing proposal - damned wrong! XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### scope

This is a difficult question to answer and account for all possible issues, because just about every workload has unique characteristics that require special attention. Some can run flawlessly using optimistic isolation levels, and others require intervention in certain areas.

In most cases, a single isolation level is not 100% right for any workload, but developer oversight, naivety, etc. can result in incorrect isolation levels being used. Whether that causes any problems or not generally comes down to luck, or lack of concurrency.

> Error messages that I can track?

For RCSI, the only errors I've ever encountered have been related to the version store filling up/running out of space. You can get some sense of what to look for by searching through available error messages:

```
SELECT
    m.*
FROM sys.messages AS m
WHERE m.language_id = 1033
AND   m.text LIKE '%[v-V]ersion [s-S]tore%'
ORDER BY
    m.message_id;
```

If you were talking about Snapshot Isolation, your bigger concern would be update conflicts:

```
SELECT
    m.*
FROM sys.messages AS m
WHERE m.language_id = 1033
AND   m.message_id = 3960
ORDER BY
    m.message_id;
```

> Snapshot isolation transaction aborted due to update conflict. You
> cannot use snapshot isolation to access table '%.*ls' directly or
> indirectly in database '%.*ls' to update, delete, or insert the row
> that has been modified or deleted by another transaction. Retry the
> transaction or change the isolation level for the update/delete
> statement.

But that's a totally different scenario.

> Diagnostic scripts I can run?

That depends on what you're attempting to diagnose. Most commonly, that would be "what's using the version store, and how much is it using?"

Here's a code fragment from [sp_PressureDetector](https://github.com/erikdarlingdata/DarlingData/blob/main/sp_PressureDetector/sp_PressureDetector.sql), slightly reformatted to respect answer length:

```
SELECT
    free_space_gb =
        CONVERT(decimal(38, 2), SUM(d.unallocated_extent_page_count * 8.) / 1024. / 1024.),
    user_objects_gb =
        CONVERT(decimal(38, 2), SUM(d.user_object_reserved_page_count * 8.) / 1024. / 1024.),
    version_store_gb =
        CONVERT(decimal(38, 2), SUM(d.version_store_reserved_page_count * 8.) / 1024. / 1024.),
    internal_objects_gb =
        CONVERT(decimal(38, 2), SUM(d.internal_object_reserved_page_count * 8.) / 1024. / 1024.)
FROM tempdb.sys.dm_db_file_space_usage AS d
WHERE d.database_id = 2;
```

If you're on SQL Server 2017 or better, you can check using something like this:

```
SELECT
    d.name,
    reserved_page_count,
    reserved_space_gb = 
        CONVERT(decimal(38, 2), reserved_space_kb / 1024. / 1024.)
FROM sys.dm_tran_version_store_space_usage AS t
JOIN sys.databases AS d
  ON t.database_id = d.database_id;
```

Note that these only monitor for version store size *in tempdb*. If you're on SQL Server 2019+ and using Accelerated Database Recovery, you'll want to monitor the Persistent Version Store.

```
SELECT
    d.name,
    persistent_version_store_size_gb = 
        CONVERT(decimal(38, 2), persistent_version_store_size_kb / 1024. / 1024.)
FROM sys.dm_tran_persistent_version_store_stats AS t
JOIN sys.databases AS d
  ON t.database_id = d.database_id;
```

> Metrics to watch?

On top of version store size, you may also want to look at long running transactions using the Version Store. Something like this may give you enough details:

```
SELECT
    at.transaction_id,
    at.name,
    at.transaction_begin_time,
    at.transaction_type,
    at.transaction_state,
    dt.is_snapshot,
    dt.first_snapshot_sequence_num,
    dt.max_version_chain_traversed,
    dt.average_version_chain_traversed,
    dt.elapsed_time_seconds
FROM sys.dm_tran_active_transactions AS at
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP (1)
           dt.*
    FROM sys.dm_tran_active_snapshot_database_transactions AS dt
    WHERE dt.transaction_id = at.transaction_id
    ORDER BY
        dt.elapsed_time_seconds DESC
) AS dt
ORDER BY
    at.transaction_begin_time DESC;
```

In general, you'd want to look for long running transactions that may be preventing version store cleanup.

> Logging the application developers can put in their own code?

I can't think of anything that would be useful.

> Specific user complaints I should be on alert for?

You would want to keep an eye on user complaints about incorrect results, or duplicative entries.

Trying to be concise here, there may be areas of the application that are sensitive to concurrency, where blocking is needed for result correctness that read committed locking provides.

I'd suggest looking at examples in these posts by Paul White:

- [Data Modifications under Read Committed Snapshot Isolation](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/data-modifications-under-rcsi)
- [The SNAPSHOT Isolation Level](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/sql-performance/the-snapshot-isolation-level)
- [The Read Committed Isolation Level](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-committed-isolation-level)
- [Sequence Tables](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/10/sequence-tables.html)

In particular, the details of just what consistency guarantees you're currently getting with read committed locking as the isolation level, and how data modifications can get odd results under read committed snapshot isolation. Queries that are sensitive to stale reads can have a READCOMMITTEDLOCK hint applied, as shown in the sequence table article.

Comment: Answers like this make me wonder if I'm just being too paranoid. Changes to isolation levels should be scary, but every hint that I'm getting is that there isn't much to watch for when you enable RCSI (tempdb aside). I dearly hope that this means that there isn't much that is likely to go wrong, as opposed to there not being much that we can _detect_ going wrong.

Comment: @J.Mini there are certainly things you should be concerned about, and preliminary tests you should do, but in general I think the guarantees that optimistic isolation levels offer are more in line with what developers expect from (and often incorrectly confer upon) read committed locking isolation. You can always dip your toes in the water by using snapshot isolation, and only allowing specific "safe" queries to use it.

Comment: @J.Mini, my understanding (which admittedly is not comprehensive enough to actually answer your question), is that although RCSI offers higher guarantees than RC, it also changes the specifics of the locking behaviour which some database applications may rely on for certain manually-crafted forms of concurrency control. Specifically, snapshot isolation may cause certain algorithms to proceed concurrently when previously they would have proceeded serially, leading to silent data corruption under certain schedules of execution.